# Does Apache configuration need to reflect Nginx upstream apache proxy in the apache LISTEN bind?

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy

Nginx is running in front of Apache and does a proxy (IP:port) for the Apache VirtualHost. When Nginx is started before Apache, Apache errors out with port already in use message. Should httpd.conf read: Listen 80 or Listen 10.7.5.53:8051?   or Listen 127.0.0.1:8051. Paste follows:

```
##NGINX
location / {
    root /var/www/wordpress/somename/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8051;
    proxy_read_timeout 1200;
    proxy_send_timeout 1200;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75
}

##APACHE                
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName somename.com
    ServerAlias www.somename.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAlias www.somename.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wordpress/somename"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Nginx listens on port 80, Apache cannot listen on that same port.  And since Nginx proxies to port 8051, I can assume Apache should be listening on port 8051, and not port 80.  1 software == 1 port, you cannot double listen.

```
User --port 80--> Nginx listen on 80 --proxy to local:8051--> Apache listen on 8051
```

So `Listen *:8051` and modify the `<VirtualHost>` for port 8051 as well.